# Ближайшие по значению понятие "mapping"

Tags: выбор-слов, терминология, переводы, английский-язык

Перевожу меню программы обнаружения мест пробития изоляции кабеля (partial discharge).

Ключевое понятие в меню - MAPPING, ближайшее значение - показать на кабеле возможные места пробоя изоляции.

```
Start mapping
Stop mapping
iPD mapping
PD mapping
```

За пару дней поиска выбрал - "картирование", что, я понимаю, относится больше к картографии и географии.

Как ближе всего по смыслу можно перевести на русский слово **mapping** не в сфере географии?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам подойдет слово *локализация* или *местоположение*.

> Обнаружение местоположения повреждения изоляции кабеля.
>
> Локализация повреждения.

Answer (score 0):

***Отображение***. Не знаю, чего тут голову ломать. Первое и  основное значение.
Причем "отображение" это именно процесс, что соответствует английскому герундию.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите варианты [здесь](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=mapping&l1=2&l2=1). Может, **разметка**?

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, в данном конкретном случае производится обработка данных диагностики (полученного графика отраженных сигналов в линии и т. п.) по методу *частичных разрядов*.

https://www.eurostell.com/methods/izmerenie-chastichnyh-razryadov/

Компьютерным методом по графику определяются места (по длине кабеля) выявленных нарушений изоляции и степень опасности каждого. Результаты переводятся в форму, удобную для оценки человеком, - обычно это *таблица*, в строках которой каждому дефекту ставится в соответствие расстояние по длине кабеля и оценка степени дефекта. Этой форме представления результатов (табулирование) и соответствует слово mapping, которое в технике обозначает, как правило, установление *соответствия* между одними данными и другими (здесь это координата дефекта,  его степень и порядковый номер). Поэтому для ясности можно предложить вариант *"**табулирование** (дефектов)"*.

Comment: Вам "PD mapping" Ничего не говорит? Какое еще табулирование? Это метод (и библиотека) для графического, **визуального** отображения.  https://www.eatechnology.com/technical-services/cable-condition-assessment/cable-partial-discharge-mapping-service/

Comment: Я найду больше примеров. Но процесс примерно такой, каким вы и описали.

Comment: @Hellseher  вы же меню переводите, при чем тут технические подробности процесса?!